# 2 radius servers connected to 1 mysql db

Tags: freeradius

I have a freeradius server with a mysql backend in production operation.  Due to a new network with segmentation issues with the NASes I need to deploy a 2nd radius server but both servers need to use the same mysql db server.  Is it safe to have 2 freeradius servers connected to a single mysql db server?

Comment: This is not remotely on topic here. This should be on [sf]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe to use multiple FreeRADIUS servers connecting to the same MySQL database. This is a standard setup when using multiple RADIUS servers for redundancy (usually with a cluster or pair of database servers in failover at the backend).